# How to make one default receiver be able to see the other receivers mail ids in ActionMailer rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am sending mails to multiple receivers at a time. I needed one **default** receiver to be able to see the ids of other receivers on his mail. And the other receivers are in BCC. I tried by setting the default mail to `to:` field and other receivers to `bcc:`. It didn't work. Following is my code.

```
  def newequip_matches_wanted
    @default_mail = "mail@mymail.com"
    @system_email = SystemEmail.find_by(title: 'Equipment matches WantedEquipment')
    @subject = @system_email.try(:subject).to_s
    @subject = "Equipment matches WantedEquipment" if @subject.blank?
    @equipment = Equipment.last
     x = Equipment.last.try(:category_id)
     y = WantedEquipment.pluck(:category_id)

     a = Equipment.last.try(:sub_category_id)
     b = WantedEquipment.pluck(:sub_category_id)
     y.include?(x) && b.include?(a)
     if true
        @receiver = WantedEquipment.where(sub_category_id: "#{a}", status: 2).pluck(:email) 
        mail(bcc: @receiver, to: @default_mail, subject: @subject)
     end
   end
```

What am I missing here? 
Question is updated.

Comment: the second one should work fine, what error you are getting, you may ahve a typo missing `,` `mail(bcc: @receiver, to:@default_mail, subject: @subject)` also, `@subject` is not defined

Comment: Sorry I will update my question. The `@default_mail` should meet the same condition as `@receiver`. This is working. `@subject` not an issue. I have defined it somewhere else. If the `@default_mail` doesn't meet the same condition as `@receiver` , the mail will be sent where it is not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You missed storing the subject into `@subject` and also you have syntax error in second code for `mail`

```
def mail
   @subject = "This is Demo subject"
   @default_mail = "mail@mymail.com"
   @receiver = Model.where(status: 2).pluck(:email) 
   mail(bcc: @receiver, to: @default_mail, subject: @subject)
end
```

[Here is a reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)

Comment: I think the `@reciever` array also contain `@default_mail` in it.